# Modal view in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

I am trying to show a view as a "modal" within my application. The main application is a tab panel and when the user does a certain action, I want to popup a view ontop of this tabpanel. I know on native iOS you can do this by pushing a view as a modal but how do I do this in Sencha?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController4', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {
            "button#mybutton": {
                tap: 'onMybuttonTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, options) {
        Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'modalpanel'});
    }
});
```

Views:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ModaPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.modalpanel',

config: {
    centered: true,
    height: 300,
    html: 'Cool Story Bro....',
    itemId: 'modalPanel',
    width: 300,
    hideOnMaskTap: true,
    modal: true,
    scrollable: true,
    hideAnimation: {
        type: 'popOut',
        duration: 200,
        easing: 'ease-out'
    },
    showAnimation: {
        type: 'popIn',
        duration: 200,
        easing: 'ease-out'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Blah Blah'
        }
    ]
}

});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Tab 1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'mybutton',
                    text: 'MyButton10'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Tab 2'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Tab 3'
        }
    ]
}

});
```

**EDIT:** 
You are probably looking for an `actionsheet` if this is not exactly what you want. See the Sencha Touch [Kitchensink](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/overlays) for the different types of Overlays.

Comment: Thanks this does help. But any way to animate the modal from bottom? Right now it kinda just appears on the screen.

Comment: what do you mean from bottom? Do you mean a slide up animation from the bottom?

Comment: Yes, I mean slide up animation from the bottom

Comment: @JohnStewart I updated my answer with a link to the Sencha Touch Kitchensink. I was aslo wondering if you were looking for something like the `actionsheet`?

Comment: @cclerville -- Why the second view? It ain't used anywhere... What is that for?